# Make JSON output grep-able?

Tags: json, linux, bash, awk, grep

My JSON output looks like this;

```
{  
   "1":{  
      "state":{  
         "on":false,
         "bri":124,
         "hue":14985,
         "sat":252,
         "effect":"none",
         "xy":[  
            0.5182,
            0.4363
         ],
         "ct":480,
         "alert":"none",
         "colormode":"xy",
         "reachable":true
      },
      "type":"Extended color light",
      "name":"Slaapkamer rechts",
      "modelid":"LCT001",
      "manufacturername":"Philips",
      "uniqueid":"00:17:88:01:00:dc:36:68-0b",
      "swversion":"66013187"
   },
   "2":{  
      "state":{  
         "on":false,
         "bri":125,
         "hue":14984,
         "sat":252,
         "effect":"none",
         "xy":[  
            0.5182,
            0.4363
         ],
         "ct":480,
         "alert":"none",
         "colormode":"xy",
         "reachable":true
      },
      "type":"Extended color light",
      "name":"Slaapkamer links",
      "modelid":"LCT001",
      "manufacturername":"Philips",
      "uniqueid":"00:17:88:01:00:dc:33:99-0b",
      "swversion":"66013187"
   }
}
```

Does anyone know a easy way to make this output grep-able? Or any other way to put the output on one line so I can use tools like grep, awk etc on the json output? 
If I do a grep right now on the word 'hue' then I get 2 lines;

```
"hue":14985,
"hue":14984,
```

While I sometimes only want to grep on the first or the 2nd one..

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you need to parse it, and I don't recommend you to do it with awk or sed. Instead use something like [jshon](http://kmkeen.com/jshon/).

Comment: Please include an example input and expected output. I can't understand what you mean with *"I sometimes only want to grep on the first or the 2nd one"*

Comment: Or you just want to remove all newlines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `jq`:

```
jq '.["1"].state.hue' file
```

Output:

```
14985
```

It is not possible to use `'.1.state.hue'` because numbers are a special case.

---

```
jq '.["2"].state.hue' file
```

Output:

```
14984
```

---

```
jq '.[].state.hue' file
```

Output:

```
14984
14985
```

Comment: jq can be found [hehe](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

Comment: JQ is exactly what I needed.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

using awk an approach

```
awk '/hue/{++count;if(count==1){print}}'
```

change count to whatever occurrence you would like to obtain